# How to use numpy in the Programmable Filter in ParaView

Tags: python, numpy, vtk, paraview

Assume, I have a ProgrammableFilter in paraview, which gets two inputs: mesh1 with data and mesh2 without. 
Furthermore, I know the permutation of the points from mesh1 to mesh2. 
Inside the filter, I can access the point values through

```
data0=inputs[0].GetPointData().GetArray('data')`
```

and obtain a part of the array using

```
subData=data0[0:6]
```

for example. But how could I add this `subData` to the output without a python loop?

To experiment with the code, I created a (not so small) working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from paraview.simple import *
import numpy as np
import vtk
from vtk.util.numpy_support import numpy_to_vtk

#generate an arbitrary source with data
mesh2=Sphere()
mesh2.Center=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
mesh2.EndPhi=360
mesh2.EndTheta=360
mesh2.PhiResolution=100
mesh2.Radius=1.0
mesh2.StartPhi=0.0
mesh2.StartTheta=0.0
mesh2.ThetaResolution=100
mesh2.UpdatePipeline()

#add the data
mesh2Vtk=servermanager.Fetch(mesh2)
nPointsSphere=mesh2Vtk.GetNumberOfPoints()
mesh2Data=paraview.vtk.vtkFloatArray()
mesh2Data.SetNumberOfValues(nPointsSphere)
mesh2Data.SetName("mesh2Data")
#TODO: use numpy here?? do this with a ProgrammableFilter ?
data=np.random.rand(nPointsSphere,1)
for k in range(nPointsSphere):
  mesh2Data.SetValue(k, data[k])
mesh2Vtk.GetPointData().AddArray(mesh2Data)

#send back to paraview server
#from https://public.kitware.com/pipermail/paraview/2011-February/020120.html
t=TrivialProducer()
filter= t.GetClientSideObject()
filter.SetOutput(mesh2Vtk)
t.UpdatePipeline()
w=CreateWriter('Sphere_withData.vtp')
w.UpdatePipeline()
Delete(w)

#create mesh1 without data
mesh1=Line()
mesh1.Point1=[0,0,0]
mesh1.Point2=[0,0,1]
mesh1.Resolution=5
mesh1.UpdatePipeline()

progFilter=ProgrammableFilter(mesh1)
progFilter.Input=[mesh1, t]
progFilter.Script="curT=inputs[1].GetPointData().GetArray('mesh2Data')"\
  "\nglobIndices=range(0,6)"\
  "\nsubT=curT[globIndices]"\
  "\nswap=vtk.vtkFloatArray()"\
  "\nswap.SetNumberOfValues(len(globIndices))"\
  "\nswap.SetName('T')"\
  "\n#TODO: how can i avoid this loop, i.e. write output.GetPointData().AddArray(converToVTK(subT))"\
  "\nfor k in range(len(globIndices)):"\
  "\n  swap.SetValue(k,subT[k])"\
  "\noutput.PointData.AddArray(swap)"
progFilter.UpdatePipeline()
w=CreateWriter('Line_withData.vtp')
w.UpdatePipeline()
Delete(w)
```

I accepted the answer, because it looks right. The following two scripts even show the problem:
base script 'run.py':

```
src1='file1.vtu'
r1=XMLUnstructuredGridReader(FileName=src1)

progFilter=ProgrammableFilter(r1)
progFilter.Input=[r1]
with open('script.py','r') as myFile:
  progFilter.Script=myFile.read()
progFilter.UpdatePipeline()
progData=progFilter.GetPointDataInformation()
print progData.GetArray('T2').GetRange()
```

and the script for the programmable filter:

```
import vtk
import vtk.numpy_interface.dataset_adapter as dsa
import numpy as np
globIndices=inputs[0].GetPointData().GetArray('T')
subT=np.ones((globIndices.shape[0],1))
subTVtk=dsa.VTKArray(subT)
output.PointData.append(subTVtk, 'T2')
```

With this combination, I get the error messages:

- File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/vtk/numpy_interface/dataset_adapter.py", line 652, in append
      self.VTKObject.AddArray(arr)

  TypeError: AddArray argument 1: method requires a VTK object
- File "run.py", line 15, in

  ```
  print progData.GetArray('T2').GetRange()
  ```

  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetRange'

The first error message stems seems to be the reason for the second one.

Comment: You have a bigger problem: using `paraview.simple` in a Programmable Filter will lead to undefined behavior and is not allowed. You must stick with pure VTK and Numpy code in a Programmable Filter. The Programmable Filter will execute on all processes running on the server side.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I tried tu construct a working example. This example is a python script, which creates the programmable filter. Inside the filter, I do not use paraview.simple, just vtk and numpy. See the line progFilter.Script = ..

Comment: You are right. Sorry for the noise. I'll add an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a minimal example that creates a VTK data array from a Numpy array. You should be able to adapt it for your purposes.

```
import numpy as np
import vtk
from vtk.numpy_interface import dataset_adapter as da

np_arr = np.ones(6)
vtk_arr = da.VTKArray(np_arr)
output.PointData.append(vtk_arr, "my data")
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I adapted it, but get the error  __TypeError: AddArray argument 1: method requires a VTK object__ in the file **/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/vtk/numpy_interface/dataset_adapter.py** in line 652. I guess, there is something odd with my paraview installation and i will go other routes.

Comment: If you post your script I can take a look.

Comment: the `vtk_arr = da.VTKArray(np_arr)` line is not needed. You should be able to simply do `output.PointData.append(np_arr, "my data")`